# How to perform ad hoc peer-to-peer WiFi discovery for cross-platform PhoneGap / Cordova app?

Tags: android, ios, sockets, cordova

I'm building a peer-to-peer game for multiple players on the same WiFi network (cross-platform iOS/Android) and am proposing to use PhoneGap with Socket.IO but am a bit confused how to get the clients to discover each other on the WiFi network so I can set up the sockets.

I'll run both a Socket.IO server and client on each device and each device will presumably need to know about every other device in order to broadcast messages.

Am I understanding things correctly here and can Socket.IO handle this or are there other plugins that can support this type of communication / discovery?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this yet but am exploring solution to the same problem of discovering peers on a LAN.

https://github.com/vstirbu/ZeroConf

I think ZeroConf is a good bet, I have used it previously on a Linux server to connect to other bonjour services. Good luck!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO @mrbfrank. Please use the answer field only if you have a solution to the problem presented. If you have only a suggestion or want to take part of the discussion, use comments like this one.